# Sql query for distinct user id on the basis of highest column value

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

Please help me to write a Django query and MySql query, I have a Table molesdetails like this:

```
+---+  +--------+  +----------+  +----------+
|id |  |user_id |  |   ref    |  |   set    |
+---+  +--------+  +----------+  +----------+
|1  |  |  1     |  |    1     |  |    1     |
|2  |  |  1     |  |    1     |  |    2     |
|3  |  |  1     |  |    2     |  |    3     |
|4  |  |  2     |  |    1     |  |    1     |
|5  |  |  2     |  |    1     |  |    2     |
|6  |  |  2     |  |    2     |  |    3     |
|7  |  |  1     |  |    2     |  |    4     |
+---+  +--------+  +----------+  +----------+
```

I want that I should get distinct ref for particular user id from the query whose set is greatest. like I want some thing Like this for `user id = 1`:

```
+---+  +--------+  +----------+  +----------+
|id |  |user_id |  |   ref    |  |   set    |
+---+  +--------+  +----------+  +----------+
|2  |  |  1     |  |    1     |  |    2     |
|7  |  |  1     |  |    2     |  |    4     |
+---+  +--------+  +----------+  +----------+
```

Please help me writing the sql query as this is becoming difficult for me to achieve this result, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all I got the result from the following query `select max(id) as id, user_id,ref, max(set) as set
  from table_name
  where user_id = 1
  group by ref;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.* 
from your_table t1
inner join
(
  select ref, max(set) as mset
  from your_table
  where user_id = 1
  group by ref
) t2 on t2.mset = t1.set and t2.ref = t1.ref
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do most of this with a basic aggregation:

```
select user_id, ref, max(set) as set
from t
group by user_id, ref
```

The question is:  how to get `id`?  Here is a method you can use in MySQL that doesn't require additional joins:

```
select substring_index(group_concat(id order by set desc), ',', 1) as id,
       user_id, ref, max(set) as set
from t
group by user_id, ref
```